# Strange MySQL CREATE TABLE behavior

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been stuck on this issue for about an hour now, and I can't solve it. Please help!

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snippets (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    code TEXT NOT NULL,
    lang_id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    dev_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    post_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    views INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (lang_id) REFERENCES languages (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

How is it possible that this query works in PHPMyAdmin and on the command line, but not in a PHP script? This is the 3rd of 6 tables that should be created. The first 2 work perfectly, but nothing after that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$link = new PDOConfig();

$link->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ratemycode");

$link->connect($link, 'ratemycode');

$queries['tables'] = array(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS developers (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        username VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS languages (
        id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS snippets (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        description TEXT NOT NULL,
        code TEXT NOT NULL,
        lang_id INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        dev_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        post_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        views INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        FOREIGN KEY (lang_id) REFERENCES languages (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        body TEXT NOT NULL,
        post_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        snip_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        dev_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snip_id) REFERENCES snippets (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
     )",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS upvotes (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        snip_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        dev_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snip_id) REFERENCES snippets (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )",
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS downvotes (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        snip_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        dev_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (snip_id) REFERENCES snippets (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (dev_id) REFERENCES developers (id),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )"
);
foreach ($queries['tables'] as $table) {
    $link->query($table);
}
```

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: I'm not getting one. In the php script, I am using a try/catch block, but a PDOException is not being thrown. Also, I should mention that this very same thing worked on Windows, but stopped as soon as a switched to Ubuntu.

Comment: so what are the two tables that were created before this code?

Comment: If the CREATE statement works at the command line but not when wrapped in a PHP script I'd suggest you look at the PHP script first

Comment: @OTTA, this very same script works perfectly in my Wamp environment. I can think of no reason it shouldn't work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using an account with sufficient privileges when connecting to the DB with PHP?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus please check out the code I added to the bottom of my question. The first two tables ('developers' and 'languages') are being created successfully from the script.

Comment: Well if you could think of the reason you wouldn't be posting here :-). Ok, what happens if you drop the third table from your script? ie does it now complete or does it still fail after the first two?

Comment: Just add backticks for column names on the problem table.

Comment: Still fails after the first two.

Comment: So either you've got exactly the same SQL issue with tables three and four, or the issue is with PHP. The fact you're using a different version supports between the working and non working environments supports that. Next thing I'd do is swap the order of your tables just to confirm I could see snippets being created.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the foreign keys and add them later with ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Thanks, but it still didn't work. As I said, the query works as is on the command line and in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing. :(

Comment: Any difference in mysql version?Also check on UBUNTU if that table is there.

Comment: There is, actually... Before, I was using 5.5.24, now it's 5.5.32. I thought about that too, but I figured that had nothing to do with it, since it works from the command line and phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to your error message, but usually this kind of error caused by foreign keys!
maybe there are differences between foreign key column and the references. 
for example maybe your reference column type is different with your foreign key!

Answer (score 0):

Ha... Turns out the changes I made in my IDE workspace were not being reflected in my /www/ directory (probably a Linux noob mistake). The code didn't run correctly the first time because this newer version of MySQL apparently doesn't allow `DATETIME` columns to have a default value returned by a function. `TIMESTAMP`s can still have a default value of `NOW()`, though. Anyways, thanks a bunch everyone.